# Can I limit the inNumberFrames passed by iOS in AURenderCallback function?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I created custom audio player class which use `AudioUnit` and `ExtAudioFile`.
In my class I prepared my own render callback function such like

```
OSStatus MyAURenderCallack (
   void                        *inRefCon,
   AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
   const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
   UInt32                      inBusNumber,
   UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
   AudioBufferList             *ioData
);
```

When my application is foreground, parameter `inNumberFrames` passed by OS is always `512` or `1024`, and my player works well.
But when the iOS device slept, `inNumberFrames` becomes `4096`, and my player doesn't work because it couldn't prepare so much frames one time.

It is difficult to improve frame preparing process, because it heavily use `extAudioFileRead` function, which is hard to accelerate.

So, I want to restrict `inNumberFrames` from becoming bigger than `1024`.
Can I make it?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `ExtAudioFileRead` in your render callback. It can block for an unspecified amount of time and cause glitching.

Comment: So should I call ExtAudioFileRead and prepare buffers in another thread?

Comment: Yes, the typical way is to have a producer thread fill a ring buffer, and the render callback reads from the ring buffer and signals the producer thread that more data is needed.

Comment: Producer-Consumer pattern worked very well. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @sbooth noted, you should really be writing to disk in another thread. If not, this puts a real stress on your application's main thread, which should be focused on delivering audio without dropouts.

But to directly answer your question: no, you cannot directly tell the OS an exact number of frames to use for the blocksize. You can advise it to use a certain latency, which combined with the requested sample rate will give you a ballpark blocksize. However, there is no guarantee that iOS will give you this blocksize back.

However, your best bet here is to make your algorithm work with arbitrary blocksizes. Unless you are doing something like convolution, it should generally be *easier* with larger blocksizes. So if you are having trouble at 4096, you should probably profile your code and see what the underlying problem is.